# SonarQube on windows - can only view locally

Tags: sonarqube

I have a windows server 2016 machine which I have Jenkins running on.  I wanted to install SonarQube.  So have downloaded v7.1

I have managed to start sonarqube on the machine and can view the webserver at http://localhost:9000

I tried to view the page on a different machine using the IP address and port 9000, but this doesn't connect.  Looking in the sonar.properties file I can see

> ## Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
>
> ## address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
>
> ## By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server. sonar.web.host=http://xx.xxx.xxxx.xxx

If I use http:// then sonarqube starts, but I can't see sonarqube from any other machine, if I don't use http:// (so just the ip) then it won't start with a bind error.

Has anyone experience of setting this up on windows?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a firewall issue?

Comment: Firewall was my first thought also, so I allowed port 9000 (which is the default) but then later found that sonarqube uses 3 different ports.  So as a test I disabled the firewall totally.  I still wasn't able to connect externally (and then reenabled the firewall)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something a lot simpler, the machine is being run on azure and there was no port 9000 endpoint